# my react js app is not working - Display react DOM error -How to fix it

Tags: reactjs

The error, Module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘react-dom/client’, is seen because you still have the previous outdated versions of “react” and “react-dom” installed in the dependencies of your project file

I would like to share the steps that helped me to fix the error; Module not found: Error: Can’t resolve ‘react-dom/client’.

this is my js files

Register component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Register() {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();

  const saveData = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = { name, email, password };
    axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/user/register`, user).then((res) => {
      alert("user registered");
      console.log(res.data);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={saveData}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter name"
          value={name}
          style={{ margin: 5 }}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="email"
          value={email}
          style={{ margin: 5 }}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Passsowrd"
          value={password}
          style={{ margin: 5 }}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <br />
        <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

Login component:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import axios from "axios";

const Login = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });

  const onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const loginHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (user.name === "" || user.password === "") {
      alert("Fill all the fields");
    } else {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:8000/user/login", {
          ...user,
        });
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("user", res.data.user._id);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("name", res.data.user.name);
        localStorage.setItem("firstLogin", true);
        console.log(res);
        alert("logged in succesfully");
        window.location.reload();
      } catch (error) {
        alert("invalid email or Password");
      }
    }
  };

  console.log(user);
  return (
    <div>
      Login
      <br />
      <br />
      <label>Email</label>
      <br />
      <input
        type="email"
        name="email"
        defaultValue={user.email}
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
      />
      <br />
      <label>Password</label>
      <br />
      <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        defaultValue={user.password}
        onChange={onChangeHandler}
      />
      <br />
      <button onClick={loginHandler}>Submit</button>
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

how can i fix this issue

Comment: function Home() {
    const [name , setName] = useState();
    const [email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [role, setRole] = useState();
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user/get').then((res) => {
        setUsers(res.data)
        console.log(res.data)
        })
       
      }, []);

Comment: It's not at all clear what that comment is supposed to be; if it's additional information for the question please edit the question--it's illegible as-is.

Comment: If the error is due to your `package.json` it might make sense to include the `package.json` file, and the *precise* error message/log, formatted.